# Interpolation for large scattered data in cloud computing

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, cloud

I am a new guy to do program, I just know some basic programming knowledge.

However, I have to do a study for the temperature & humidity at different location for several cities. There are about hundreds to thousands measurement points (latitude and longitude). Then I have to use those points to do interpolation / extrapolation and generate millions of points to get the temperature & humidity.

Probably use a cloud computing to do this task and google cloud is the preferable choice.

So is it only true that Python can do this task? If we do it in java, is it possible, especially running in cloud?

There are some scripts for reference in Python for Inverse distance weighting, IDW, seems only python can help on this if we use google cloud, right? I am still understanding how to use the python language on the google cloud. If there is any reference script which can be used directly, it will be thankful.

See if anyone can provide some advice for this.

Comment: Why does Google Cloud have to be implemented?
Yes, either of those will work. In fact, this is possible in most modern languages.

Comment: Because we would like to do a real time monitoring.
And the data is obtained each hour in the internet. Better to do it cloud computing.
Is python the best choice to do this calculation? Grateful if anyone comes across this please share the experience.

Comment: Do you own the sensors? How are you getting your data?

Comment: Basically we would like to use the weather station from the local government to do this study. So we got the latitude and longitude of each point and the temperature data at each point.
That's why we will do it in the google app engine.
We fixed to use python.